# Roslyn Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Scripting .NET 4.7.1 Problems

Tags: c#, roslyn

I'm using the Roslyn library to execute dynamic c# scripts:

https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/

For some reason, it only works on .NET framework 4.6.  Upgrading to 4.7.1 throws the following errors:

> FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'System.Runtime, Version=4.0.20.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified.

I have updated and reinstalled the Nuget package:

> Install-Package Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Scripting

Any ideas what could be wrong?

UPDATE

I read that creating a .Net Standard project and implementing Roslyn there while referencing the project solves the issues.  I did not find this to work at all